# Error 0X80004005 in SSIS while trying to connect to Excel sheet

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm getting in some sheets (not all) of an Excel file this error when I use the EXCEL SOURCE component in SSIS: Error 0X80004005

i HAVE ERASED before two sheets in the data flow task.I have tried to create those same sheets but it throws an error (see below the image). And now some of the 24 sheets are not working at all. I have not changed the original excel filename, neither the names of the sheets. Even if I open a new package and try to recreate the data flow task...  it still throws this error!! How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: See if you change to sql command and try hardcoding your range: SELECT [fieldnames...] from [Sheet1$A2:F] where A2 to f unknown is the range on sheet1

Comment: Keith, when I try to build the query for the sheet is not working... it does not appear the names of the columns of that sheet!!   If I choose a sheet is workking, the names of the columns appear! I do not know why this happens! Any ideas?

Comment: I have closed the Microsoft Visual Studio... now I could see ONLY one column for one sheet  but the others columns do not appear! what the heck is happening? EDIT: now I cannot create any at all. I have renamed the ORIGINAL excel file to a new name , I only have added _2 and it seems it is working. Something rather odd have happened with the SSIS.. must be a bug!